# Hazelcast port not getting killed

Tags: jakarta-ee, hazelcast, weblogic12c

In our application, Hazelcast gets initialized as part of the Server (Weblogic 12C) startup and shutdown is called during server shutdown.

On Shutdown we are using the following code:
hz.getLifecycleService().shutdown();

During server startup, we are getting the following exception
SEVERE: Port [6713] is already in use and auto-increment is disabled. Hazelcast cannot start

Hence, The restart of our deployment is not working.

Workaround: As a workaround, we need to kill the process and restart the Server. Not an ideal workaround.
is there some setting to be done at the OS level ?

If anyone has faced this issue, please help us to resolve.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.AddressPicker.pickAddress(AddressPicker.java:85)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.Node.<init>(Node.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.<init>(FactoryImpl.java:386)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.newHazelcastInstanceProxy(FactoryImpl.java:133)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.newHazelcastInstanceProxy(FactoryImpl.java:119)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.newHazelcastInstanceProxy(FactoryImpl.java:104)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:507)
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception is happening because the previous node didn't shutdown properly and could be in hanging state.

Try adding a shutdown hook in another thread itself for graceful shutdown. Add the below code snippet in a method and call it while starting the node.

```
Runtime
.getRuntime()
    .addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> hazelcastInstance.getLifecycleService().shutdown()));
```